# How to avoid compiler warning when using PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP and -Wextra

Tags: c, gcc, pthreads

I want to use GCC compiler option -Wextra in my project.
But it causes problems with PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP.

The following code:

```
static pthread_mutex_t g_mutex = PTHREAD_RECURSIVE_MUTEX_INITIALIZER_NP;
```

Causes the following warning:

```
test.c:39: warning: missing initializer
test.c:39: warning: (near initialization for `g_mutex.__data.__nusers')
```

Is there any way to avoid that warning?

Gcc version is 3.4.5. and pthread version is 2.3.5.

Comment: gcc is supposed to avoid issuing warnings for things that came from system headers. I wonder if your gcc is just too old, or if you're including pthread.h wrong (maybe with `""` instead of `<>`?) so gcc doesn't treat it as a system header..?

Comment: The warning isn't coming from a system header; it's coming from test.c; and therefore isn't suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

With recent GCC versions (not the one you mention, I'm afraid) you can silence such warnings with the option `-Wno-missing-field-initializers`.